# Can we pass a reference that can be modified, in a function?

Tags: function, kotlin

It turns out that we cannot pass a reference in a function that can be modified. As this code fails to compile

```
fun(i: Int){
    i = 10
}
```

Is there a way we can pass references that can be modified. Or does the language itself does not support this feature

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're interested in changing the value of `i` only within the function, or whether you want it to have effects outside the function too?  Also, did you omit the function name by accident, or is it an [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) (which is an expression and a closure)?

Answer (score 2):

The function parameters in Kotlin are read-only but you can make work around like that.

```
fun(i: Int){
   var newI = i
   newI = 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify it directly, but you can pass a container to the function to make it possible:

```
class Container(var i: Int)

fun assign(container: Container) {
    container.i = 10
}

fun main() {
    val container = Container(1)
    assign(container)
    println(container.i)
}
```

You may also consider passing an one-element array instead:

```
fun assign(a: Array<Int>) {
    a[0] = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve it with reflection

```
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty0

fun modifyInt(i: KMutableProperty0<Int>) {
    i.set(10)
}
```

Calling the function like...

```
modifyInt(::myMutableInt)
```